# Display time duration in a html input field

Tags: javascript

I have tried long time but i failed, please help,

```
var set_time = document.getElementById('set');
set_time.onclick = function start_time() {
    var myDate = new Date();
```

then make a custom time

```
var h = myDate.getHours();
    var m = myDate.getUTCMinutes();
    var s = myDate.getSeconds();
    var time = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
```

after that set the time in an input field

```
document.getElementById('start').value = time;
};
```

same as above set end time

```
var end_time = document.getElementById('end');
end_time.onclick = function end_time() {
    var myDate = new Date();
```

store end time an input field

```
var time = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
    document.getElementById('stop').value = time;
};
```

now i want to find difference or duration and set in an input field "duration"

```
function duration(){
  var start= document.getElementById('start').value;
  var stop = document.getElementById('stop').value;

  // i want to calculate duration and  display the duration in an input field

  document.getElementById('duration').value = result;

};
setInterval(duration, 1000);
```

Comment: Define "I failed.". Did you get an error? What result are you getting? Where do you think you are going wrong?

Comment: Clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be written better, but for readability: [PEN](https://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/QvRjvM)

```
  var start= document.getElementById('start').value;
  var stop = document.getElementById('stop').value;

  var startVal = document.getElementById('start').value.split(':');
  var stopVal = document.getElementById('stop').value.split(':');
  var h = (parseInt(stopVal[0])-parseInt(startVal[0]))*3600;
  var m = (parseInt(stopVal[1])-parseInt(startVal[1]))*60;
  var s = (parseInt(stopVal[2])-parseInt(startVal[2]))
  var dur = h+m+s;

  var hOut = Math.floor(dur/3600)
  var mOut = Math.floor((dur-hOut*3600)/60)
  var sOut = dur-hOut*3600-mOut*60
  var result = hOut+':'+mOut+':'+sOut
  if (!isNaN(sOut)) document.getElementById('duration').value = result;
```

EDIT: another version, using dates:

```
  var start= document.getElementById('start').value;
  var stop = document.getElementById('stop').value;
  if (!start || !stop) return;

  var startVal = new Date(zeroDay+start+timeZone)
  var stopVal = new Date(zeroDay+stop+timeZone)

  var dur = stopVal-startVal

  var result = new Date(dur-60*60*1000)
  document.getElementById('duration').value = result.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
```

Where 'zeroDay' is first day in history (of Date) - 1/1/1970. [PEN](https://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/EmBxJr)

Comment: thanks a lot.. its works well but this code is too complex and i cant understand.... if any other easy solution then it could be better for me...
i just want to set a button to start which contain the start time of any meeting and then a stop button containing the end time and finally find the duration... i know the basic javascript but i want to learn.....

Comment: I'm afraid this task won't get much easier, as there's no native "duration" support in JS, but I've edited code with another example.